# How feasible is a question on keeping produce fresh?

Tags: discussion, answers, canonical

We have some great answers that serve as general lists on food safety, how long things last in the refrigerator, etc. Would it be a good idea to have one on how best to keep produce fresh? For example:

- Berries keep fresh for up to two weeks if [refrigerated in a closed glass jar](http://www.chowhound.com/post/fresh-strawberries-glass-jars-weeks-perfect-301817)
- Tomatoes [lose flavor if refrigerated](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2014/03/22/storing-tomatoes.aspx)
- Mushrooms keep well if [refrigerated in a brown paper bag](https://lifehacker.com/5831132/use-brown-paper-bags-to-keep-mushrooms-dry-and-fresh) that has been rolled closed
- Cilantro keeps well if [placed in water, covered, and refrigerated](http://www.vegetablegardener.com/item/12215/how-to-keep-cilantro-fresh)

I'm guessing this would be a community wiki type post rather like the one on [similar sounding terms with different meanings](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16076/what-international-cooking-terms-sound-similar-but-have-different-meanings).

Good idea? Impractical? Bad idea?

Comment: As a note, the tomato/refrigerator rule is actually contested...

Answer (score 3):

This sounds to me like there would be too many combinations of produce, temperatures, humidity requirements, container types, ventilation, and even proximity to other produce to have one, big comprehensive answer.

I would suggest to continue hosting these questions on an as-needed basis. Then if you find yourself answering a group of these with essentially the *same* answer, that is a good use case for finally creating a great canonical post to handle that particular situation. But probably *not* one for *all produce.*